# Mist Wallet vs Account - How do I send ether from Wallet to exchange?

Tags: wallets, mist

I am on a mac using Mist. I have 1 ether in my account and a few more in my wallet. How do I send ether from my wallet to an exchange? I see that I can deposit bitcoin but I can't withdraw ether... Do I need to do this via the command line? When I hover over my wallet it reads "watch only" and in the top right hand corner it shows my account balance not my wallet balance. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like a serious issue here. How did you create the wallets? You can not access watch-only wallets. Which private keys were used to generate them?

Answer (score 7):

You need to make an account at an exchange like [Poloniex](https://poloniex.com) or [Kraken](https://kraken.com). They will then provide you with an address where you can deposit Ether. You can also use [Shapeshift](https://shapeshift.io), which allows you to exchange ETH for BTC or other cryptocurrencies.

Then just click on the account in Mist that you want to send from, and click the send button up at the top. Send the ether to the address that the exchange provided.

Note that Shapeshift does not currently support sending from smart contract wallets, so send to an account first, then to Shapeshift.

See [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/212/whats-the-difference-between-accounts-and-wallets-in-mist) for the difference between accounts and wallets.

Comment: I was going to suggest cex.io for another exhange. It was pretty quick and pain less to get my limits up. Kraken was a bit of a pain but I assume thats because am in the states ? Kraken has the better ETH exchange rates... most of the time though.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn' send ether to Kraken from a contract wallet at all.

> Kraken.com: Attention! Send only normal transactions with an amount larger than 10 GWei / Shannon. Do not send from a contract wallet. Contracts crediting your deposit address without a proper transaction won't result in a valid deposit.

Answer (score 1):

If the wallet says *"watch only"* you have no control of the wallet contract.

A contract based wallet, like these created in mist, are *externally owned*. To import them, you use the public key of the wallet contract in mist.

[image: import wallet]

To actually use them, you also have to make sure to import the backup of your account's private key which is *owning* the wallet contract.

```
geth account import /path/to/keystore/backup/UTC--2016-02-02T00-36-01.611176405Z--00006314ee6ba5a9421e4aa6a47c6867a882bd92
```

This will turn a watch only wallet into a fully accessable.

You have backups, don't you?

Comment: I backed up the keystore. It looks similar to what you have above. UTC--2016... In the terminal, it asks for my passphrase. I enter my passphrase and it says Fatal: Could not create the account: open /path/to/keystore/backup/UTC--2016-....-- no such file or directory... I can see the contract on the chain but can't understand why I can't access it. All I want to do is transfer the 25 ether to Kraken... Now the contract doesn't even show up on my Mist GUI...