# On Mist, can I create a .json file wallet protected by a password (or not) just like ethereumwallet?

Tags: wallets, json-rpc, password

Wll basically tht is the question on the latest Mist version, can I create a .json file wallet protected by a password (or not) just like I did using ethereumwallet.com?

Answer (score 1):

The key file is called [web3 secret storage](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Web3-Secret-Storage-Definition) (and version 3 is used today).

This format makes a password mandatory, but doesn't put a restriction on the password length. It can be zero. Or could be something really long.

There are various tools (wallets), which can export a V3 file. ethereumwallet.com (and I think myethereumwallet too) will use an empty password ('') for the *unencrypted* wallets.

On my local geth I've hit enter on both password fields and got a file with password of '':

```
$ geth account new
Your new account is locked with a password. Please give a password. Do not forget this password.
Passphrase:
Repeat Passphrase:
```

Note: even with this, the file is still *encrypted*, albeit with the empty password. You need to remember it uses the empty password.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean up some confusion here.

1. **Mist** is actually a browser. It is meant to be used to browse decentralized applications in the future. During the development process it only supports one DApp: the Ethereum Wallet DApp. see: [github/ethereum/mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist)
2. **Ethereum Wallet DApp**: Is the wallet software you refer to when saying "mist". That's okay, because it currently really almost is the same. The wallet DApp runs inside mist. see: [github/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet)
3. Both mist and the wallet require a client (ethereum node) in the backend which could either be **geth** or **eth** (or really any other ethereum client). Currently, the mist browser includes all of them: mist browser, dapp wallet and a client for the backend. see: [github/ethereum/go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) for geth and [github/ethereum/webthree-umbrella](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella) for eth.

Now that you understand that not Mist is the wallet, but the DApp provides the wallet functionality **on top of** (probably) **geth**, you can simply use the JSON-RPC API, the console and the keystore of geth. To backup your keys, check `~/.ethereum/keystore` on Linux or checkout the other threads for other methods:

- [How to backup mist wallets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/946/87)
- [How to backup my ether accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/108/87)
- [What's the difference between Accounts and Wallets in Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/212/87)

Comment: Thank you, everything was going smooth until the last paragraph when you say "you can simply..." then I got lost. Basecally how do I back up my eth account when using the wallet DApp on Mist?

Comment: For backing up the Wallet DApp see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-backup-mist-wallets