# Can a contract pay its own fees?

Tags: ether, fees

so I've been working on ethereum for the past few weeks, mainly deploying and interacting with contracts but something i noticed is the high gas usage of using the tokens over time, so i was wondering if there may be a way to save the gas for users who would use my contract? like is there a way that a contract may pay its own fees? if I give it enough ether ofcourse... I want to be able to let users with 0 ether use my contract, any help or direction would be much appericiated! :)

thanks for your help.

Comment: Also related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/823/what-is-the-way-to-make-ethereum-available-to-users-for-free