# How to send custom tokens without ether?

Tags: solidity, tokens, out-of-gas, gas-refund

I would like my customers to send a custom token without thinking of a certain amount of ether for gas. So I've tried the standard-token at ethereum.org. There's a way described to auto refill the sender address:

**Then, add this line to the transfer function so that the sender is refunded:**

```
/* Send coins */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    ...
    if(msg.sender.balance<minBalanceForAccounts)
        sell((minBalanceForAccounts-msg.sender.balance)/sellPrice);
}
```

But that only works if the sender got ether at least once, as a zero amount of ether will prevent the first token tx.

Is there any way, that my customers don't need to care about ether when they exchange my Dentacoin token?

(I could add a contract, that sends ether to all addresses listed in the token address mapping, but that contract would be drained very soon, right?)

I appreciate any ideas!

Comment: See also [What is the way to make Ethereum available to users for free?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/823/87) and [How interact with Ethereum without (gas) ether?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/82/87)